# How to configure Angular app so everyone can use it against backend GCP

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform

I have this Angular Client app at Google Cloud platform and it doing Crud operations to ASP.NET Core also at GCP. The problem is only I can use the app.

My Friend using his laptop cant connect nobody can except from my computer when I use it.

How to configure this so everyone can use this app:

https://angular-v4-dot-unique-yew-244216.appspot.com/#/search

What am I missing?

At GCP in the log for the backend every time I search there is a corresponding log entry and I get results but only when I search from my development computer

This is my db to search on: try search for Title Rain

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="B1">
    <author>Kutner, Joe</author>
    <title>Deploying with JRuby</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>33.00</price>
    <publish_date>2012-08-15</publish_date>
    <description>Deploying with JRuby is the missing link between enjoying JRuby and using it in the real world to build high-performance, scalable applications.</description>
  </book>
  <book id="B2">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
    <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen of the world.</description>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

GCP Log only show entries when I search

[image]

Comment: It seems to work. Maybe your friend need to clear his browser cache.

Comment: Thanks very strange this we do what you say but still no search work, but I see that you could search

Comment: Open this page from a mobile never works

Comment: Ok it works now! The Google Cloud Platform has the traffic splitting, I had 50% on Angular and 50% on ASP.NET backend. Now I put 90% on ASP.NET and 10% on Angular, yes then it works! In no tutorial and not even during deploy does GCP warn about this

Answer (score 0):

Ok it works now!
The Google Cloud Platform has this traffic splitting, I had 50% on Angular and 50% on ASP.NET backend. Now I put 90% on ASP.NET and 10% on Angular, yes then it works! In no tutorial and not even during deploy does GCP warn about this...